# Wicked PDF unable to handle page break

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

I'm using **gem wiked_pdf** in my Rails application that generates report.

But I'm having trouble fixing the breaking of data when having more that 1 page.

Please see image.[image]

I tried many time to adjust the margin or spacing, but still unable to fix it.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    render title:         @report_title,
           pdf:           @report_title,
           template:      'applicants/generate_report.pdf.erb',
           encoding:      'UTF-8',
           orientation:   'Landscape',
           layout:        'pdf_template.html',               
           footer: {
                    center:    '[page] of [topage]',
                    right:     "",
                    font_name: 'Arial',
                    font_size: 8                        
                   },
           margin: {
                    top:     10, # default 10 (mm)
                    bottom:  12,
                    left:    7,
                    right:   7 
                   },
          spacing: 0
  end
end
```

I also tried to apply **CSS**, like:

```
@media print {
  td, tr {page-break-inside: avoid; }
  table.full_report_table>tbody>tr>td {page-break-inside: avoid !important; }
}
```

Nothing works!

Please help!

Answer (score 6):

**SOLVED**

**Yes**,

> page-break-inside: avoid;

it is working properly in **div** tag.

But it took me awhile and had rough research, to figure out how to make it work with  **long tables**.

Adding some **CSS** style do the trick for me.

As in documentation [W3 page-break](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/page.html#page-breaks), it will work with block element.

What I did was to add **display style** together with it.

```
<tr style="page-break-inside: avoid; display: inline-table;">
```

Either, **inline-table** or **inline-block** works in my case.

I hope this will help others who encounter the same error as mine.

Comment: `display: inline-block;` in addition to `page-break-inside: avoid;` is what finally got this working for me. I think the combination of these two needs to be emphasized more. Thanks for doing so!

Comment: Yes. it solved the issue. but than there is alignment issue in `display: inline-table`

Comment: @aldrien page break issue is resilved but due to display: inline-table CSS, my design spoil, can you please give me sugesstion to resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one class and apply below CSS into it :

```
div.alwaysbreak { page-break-before: always; }
```

For Example, In my case :

```
<div class="alwaysbreak">
   // My PDF Template
</div>
```

Hope this helps..!

Comment: Hi @Hardik, I just tried the given css in wicked_pdf documentation. It seems like the styles only works with <div> and not in table ? But currently my template uses table, since it renders many data.

Comment: I have implemented the same, and It works for me..
Have you include CSS using `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag` ?

Comment: Hi @Hardik, yes I used wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag declaring sa CSS on my pdf template. Have you tried to use that css in tr or td tags ? Doesn't worked on me.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten around this issue in the past by wrapping each table row in a `div` with the css `page-break-inside: avoid;`.

I know it isn't semantically correct, but it works.

That should ensure it transitions pages without cutting off table content in the middle of a row:

```
<style>
  .nobreak:before {
    clear: both;
  }
  .nobreak {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
</style>
<table>
  <div class="nobreak">
    <tr>
      <td>First row</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
  <div class="nobreak">
    <tr>
      <td>Second row</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried to add border to see how it renders, and it not working properly, due to invalid HTML structure.

Comment: Hm. It definitely used to. Maybe try the div inside the `<tr>`? As an alternative, you could make each row it's own table, and wrap that in a div. That means your `<td>`'s might need to be fixed width, or it won't look too much like a table.

Answer (score 0):

Simplty put a div at last of your html code. like

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <% if question.id == @questions.last.id %>
    <div></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

After adding a division in your html.put the following line in your css:

```
div.alwaysbreak { page-break-before: always; }
div.nobreak:before { clear:both; }
div.nobreak{ page-break-inside: avoid; }
```

It works for me